# Failure: plugin grpc-gateway: could not find protoc plugin for name grpc-gateway -

Tags: go, grpc

while genrating Prot buff using "buf generate"
i am getting below error :

Failure: plugin grpc-gateway: could not find protoc plugin for name grpc-gateway - please make sure protoc-gen-grpc-gateway is installed and present on your $PATH

i have tried installtion of
"go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest; "

Answer (score 4):

```
$ go install github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway@latest
$ go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest
$ go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest
```

then check for your path , if its not set then use below command :

```
PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/go/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is specifically for `protoc-genc-grpc-gateway` which is distinct from `proto-gen-go-grpc`.

See the [Installation](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway#installation) instructions that include `protoc-gen-grpc-gateway`.

You will also need that the plugin is in your host's `PATH`. On Linux you can `which protoc-gen-grpc-gateway` to confirm this after installation.

Comment: yes, issue was on my PATH variable.
this line fixed my problem :  *PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/go/bin"*